# unable to redirect output of batch command to text file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to list the file name and filesize in windows.The output is displaying in console But i couldnt able to redirect the output to text file.Please help

Below are the commands used which are successfully displaying result on console

@echo off

for /f %a in ('dir d:\test  /s /b') do  echo %~fa %~za

But if i tried to rediect to text file called "a.txt" ,only last file result has been redirected,not complete result(there are many files in the directory "d:\test")

for /f %a in ('dir d:\test  /s /b') do  echo %~fa %~za >a.txt

type a.txt

d:\test\test2\a.txt 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using append `>>`, not create `>` in your code

```
for /f %a in ('dir d:\test /s /b') do echo %~fa %~za >>a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two redirecting symbols instead of one